# How can I change a color permanent on a tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a button click I have following code inside my .Post():

```
if (Comment != null && Grade > 0) {
    $("navigation").attr('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]')
                   .css({ "background-color": "green" });
} else if (Comment == null && Grade == null) {
    $('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').css({ "background-color": "#D8D8D8" });
```

If I close my webapplication or just refresh it the color is gone. How can I make the color stay forever even if i close or refresh Do I have to addclass or something?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "permanent"?

Comment: that it alters the webpage what is impossible, except for when he edits the source files. @Tieson

Comment: What I mean is that the colors stays even if you refresh or close the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so short answer: **you can't**.

**Long answer:** CSS files are stored on the **remote** server and served as requested (via the `<link />` tag in the head of your HTML document). JavaScript is executed on your **local** machine, in the browser (unless you're running node.js, I suppose). So your changes only exist as long as that particular scripting instance/page view is running. Reloading the page re-requests (depending on cache settings) the CSS file and reloads it.

So, unless you want users to be able to freely modify your server files (a monumentally-bad idea), you really can't do what it seems you want to...

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Move this code to javascript function, for example, function colorChange() and call this function onLoad() and onClick()(when button pressed).

Comment: can't do that with the functionality that page have

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to find a way to mark it permanently, like adding a class, because then you could edit your css and it's solved.
I suppose you are trying to post a comment? Add that class or something in you server side code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your state of color in browser cookie, else you can't handle page refresh.
Save the change in color in cookie, and add onLoad handler which should check if cookie exists and mark the change accordingly

I assume you are using jQuery so you can try

```
$.cookie("colorSet", "true", { expires: 7 });
```

and onLoad method of your page you can check again

```
$.cookie("colorSet") == "true"
```

make your changes again.

Answer (score -1):

In jquery you can add a class when the click function is done:

```
$(".navigation").onclick{function(){
        $(".class_name").addClass(); 
    }
)};
```